# Python: Convert all integer- and floatstrings in a dict to their numerical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dict with several numerical values expressed as strings. Is there a pythonic way to convert all strings that contain an int to an int and all that contain a float to a float?
For example

```
{'top': {'val1': '123', 'val2': '1.23'}, 'top2': '123'}
```

To

```
{'top': {'val1': 123, 'val2': 1.23}, 'top2': 123}
```

Comment: The most pythonic way is probably to not use the wrong type in the first place :-P

Comment: Please share your code with an example

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann I get the response from an external API wrapper

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do to determine if something is a float is look for the location of a "."

```
if "." in string:
    result = float(string)
else:
    result = int(string)
```

If you are not sure if the input is convertible to a number, use try-except

```
try:
if "." in string:
    result = float(string)
else:
    result = int(string)
except:
    print("Invalid")
```

Or something like that. However, if you want "5.0", for example, to be counted as an int, not a float, there is an elegant way:

```
if int(string)==float(string):
    result = int(string)
else:
    result = float(string)
```

Essentially if int() doesn't change the value, it uses that. Otherwise, it uses float()